# Analogous Euler line of a hyperbolic triangle

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

What curve passes through the circumcentre C, orthocentre O and centre of gravity G of a hyperbolic triangle? Would it be hyperbolically straight? Any ratio of hyperbolic distances among them?

If the plane is flat and the geometry euclidean ( i.e., when the constant pseudo-radius goes to infinity), then they lie on the Euler straight line.

Comment: Well, not every hyperbolic triangle has a circumcenter, so that's a problem. ... The 2000 paper ["The Euler Line in Hyperbolic Geometry" (PDF link via genseo.edu)](https://www.geneseo.edu/~josm/1-1/00-03.pdf) by Klus gives a counterexample to collinearity. (The paper goes on to assert that no non-equilateral triangle has an Euler line, but this is false: isosceles triangles w/circumcenters clearly do.) It's actually pretty straightforward to construct a counterexample in GeoGebra on the Poincaré Disk by taking the right triangle w/right angle at the origin and other vertices on the coord axes.

Comment: So here you disagree with Klus?

Comment: Klus' concluding remark is *"In fact, a counterexample was found for all types of triangles, with the exception of the equilateral triangle."* But the circumcenter (when it exists), orthocenter, and centroid of an *isosceles* triangle all lie on its line of symmetry, which is therefore also its Euler line. So, yes, I disagree with Klus' concluding remark, because it is false. ... That said, I went through some ugly coordinate-bashing in the Poincare disk; if I haven't erred (which I haven't double-checked), I have confirmed that no *scalene* triangle in the hyperbolic plane has an Euler line.

Comment: Thanks. Very interesting, shall dabble into the hyperbolic straight "Euler" line